# change parent for a sprite

Tags: android, andengine

I have two sprite  **BOX & EasyEnemy**. They attached on the scene already, and they moves randomly. When they collides with each other I want to attach easy enemy as a child of the BOX sprite.

The EasyEnemy comes from a the generic pool in the scene. I iterate over all **EasyEnemy** inside BOX sprite onManageUpdate() & BOX sprite create as usual.

Here is my code:

```
private void moveBox() {
    aBox = new Sprite(0, 0, aResourceManager.boxTexture, vBOM) {

        @Override
        protected void onManagedUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
            // Iterate over all Easy Enemy
            eIt = getEasyEnemyIterator();
            while (eIt.hasNext()) {
                final EasyEnemy ee = eIt.next();
                if (this.collidesWith(ee)) {
                    aResourceManager.mEngine
                            .runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    ee.clearEntityModifiers();
                                    ee.clearUpdateHandlers();
                                    ee.setIgnoreUpdate(true);
                                    ee.reset();                                     

                                    ee.setParent(aBox);
                                    aBox.attachChild(ee);

                                }
                            });

                }

            }

            super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

        }

    };
    attachChild(aBox);
    aBox.registerEntityModifier(new MoveModifier(15, 360, 360, 0, 1200));
    aBox.setZIndex(9990);
}
```

I got error like

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2876): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
E/AndroidRuntime(2876): java.lang.IllegalStateException: pEntity 'EasyEnemy' already has a parent: ''. New parent: ''!
E/AndroidRuntime(2876):     at org.andengine.entity.Entity.assertEntityHasNoParent(Entity.java:1412)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I collision occurs this method is called multiple time, thus trying to attach a child o a parent multiple times and you already know that a Child can have only one parent at a time.
So either you need to change the logic so that the collision method is called only once or you need to call 
ee.detachself() before ee.setParent(aBox);

Comment: no change when use  ee.detachself()  before ee.setParent(aBox); @Jawad Amjad Vai

Comment: after adding a check I got it.@Jawad Amjad Vai.